Is it possible to assign IP address to clients on LAN from DHCP server on WAN?
I have a setup including a Ubuntu SERVER, TP-link Router(ER7212PC), a company managed network and several Control Boards (clients in picture). The Server is running dnsmasq and the client boards are set up to connect to HOST:abcontrol on port: 5000. dnsmasq is configured on enp2s0 (LAN2 port), dynamic-bind, DHCP-range: 192.168.11.50,192.168.11.150,12h. When a control board is connected directly to the LAN 2 port, the control board gets an IP assigned and a program running on the SERVER can communicate with the board as designed.
Here is my issue.
I have several of those Control Boards at different places at the site, and due to security reasons, the company requested i used something managed and sent me a TP-link Router. In order to get this working as designed, I need the Control Boards connected to the Router to get their IP from the Control Server. This has to be done over the Company Network, and on the LAN1 (enp1s0) on the Control Server, without changing the HOST setting on the Control Boards. I have a total of 4 Routers that needs to be set up this way and they are of the same model.
I have full access to the TP-link and Server, and I can probably request the company to edit stuff on the network if needed, but I have not found a way to do this yet. Any tips on how this can be achieved? Any help would be verry much appreciated


Your mistaken in thinking that the Corporate Network is on a WAN address.  The addresses on your diagram all start with 10.  See Private IPv4 addresses.  The WAN port was used as the connection interface to designate that the incoming corporate LAN traffic comes from outside your LAN segment.  Can the TP Link Managed Router be Configured to hand out addresses in the 16-bit block?

Yeah, the diagram was more to comment which port on the router the Company LAN was connected to. Do you mean if the Router can hand out Ip's as a DHCP? In that case, yes it can. I was thinking about making the same subnet on the router as the Control Server (192.168.11.0/24) and maybe routing traffic from enp1s0 to enp2s0. But I believe the program on the Control Server uses the ip's stored in /lib/var/dnsmasq.leases, so I'm out of ideas to get that set up. I've also looked up DHCP relay, but my knowledge on networking is limited.

This would take some planning, but as my first attempt, I would use a MAC address filter and setup the tp-link router to hand out the 192.168.1.x address provided via dnsmasq. Setup DNSMasq to always give the same address using the MAC filter, and then activate the same MAC Filter on the TP-Link side.  This should work as all the communication occurs in the same subnet

This is well above my knowledge. Do you have a link that can describe the MAC filter and setup? And I have been browsing around in the Router settings for quite some time, but I can't recall ever seeing anything like MAC address filtering.

I know it's Fedora but see Item3

I found it:  That router uses a fancy name for MAC Filtering called Address Reservation. See Specifications - Basic Functions - Address Reservation.  Since I don't have access to the Management UI or screenshots, I can't give you more....

I’m voting to close this question because it is more about router's DHCP address reservation, and networking question than anything to do with Ubuntu.

Hmm.. I will have to look at this when I'm on-site tomorrow. But do I understand it correctly that I have to add the Mac and Ip's manually? Both on the Control Server and the Router?

I suggest you move the client attached to the Ubuntu server to the TP-Link Omada Router. Use the Omada router's address reservation to assign fixed IP addresses based on each client's MAC adderss. Use the Omada router's NAT to allow remote access from the Ubuntu server to various clients if needed. You have to add the address reservation rules (map the MAC to specific IP addresses) manually in the router's settings. Same goes for the NAT rules. I am not sure if you need to do anything to the Ubuntu server other than use different ports to remotely access different clients.

Thanks for the input. I can't make the router do all the addressing as the clients are in 4 different buildings. So i have 4 routers in total. And the LAN that is currently set up to handle this is plugged into a simple switch connected to several Control Boards (clients). But i agree that this is probably not the place to ask these questions. Any suggestion to where I can ask that might be more fitting to my case?

Read up on Network Address Translation (NAT) and port forwarding. See this answer for an example of port forwarding. In your case the external port will be different for each client and the Ubuntu server will have to be configured that way.

Yes, you'll need to manually configure both sides, and I tend to agree with @user6186 in his suggestion about moving the server.  Moving said server would remove the need to configure identical "sides", and in each case(4) each router will need to be configured identically. Get one working and repeat the process 3 more timees

You have not said which protocol the clients and the servers use to communicate. If you use ssh for example, to remotely connect from the server to the clients, you will need port forwarding. If the clients initiate the connection to the server say using http, no port forwarding would be needed, just has home computers can connect to the websites on the Internet via home routers using NAT.

I thank you both for your time and suggestions. I think, as you stated, this is more of a Router/Networking question than an Ubuntu question. I thought there might be something I could do on the Control Server as that is the HOST the control bords are set up to "look for". I was thinking it would be possible for the clients to request an IP from the DHCP on the Server. Like maybe set up all traffic from the Router to the company LAN and direct it to the Server on 10.123.123.62 (enp1s0) port 5000 and filter that to the DHCP on 192.168.11.1 (enp2s0). But I don't know enough about networks.

DHCP requires the server to be reached by broadcasting a request, and such traffic is limited to a local subnet. Thus, if the client is on a different subnet than the server, the request will never reach the server. However, you may be able to achieve this by setting up a UDP Relay on the router. This does more than simply forward the broadcast packets. It also examines, checks their validity, and adds any appropriate changes. I haven't personally configured a setup like this, but theoretically it's possible. Of course, your router will need to be capable, and you'll need to do your homework.

I'm also flagging this question as off-topic, because it's about configuring your router and not your Ubuntu Server.

The built-in Omada SDN controller allows the ER7212PC to manage and update your devices in bulk, without the need for complex individual configuration. Additionally, if you check the Omada app or web browser, the ER7212PC allows you to remotely control connected devices, monitor the network, and view network health in real time.
